# Xcode 8.1 does not detect when an objective-c method is not defined

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

EDITED

I discovered new information. This question can be deleted.
See the new question [In a static library, Xcode 8.1 does not detect when an objective-c method is not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819127/in-a-static-library-xcode-8-1-does-not-detect-when-an-objective-c-method-is-not)

---

Recently I just discovered that Xcode 8.1 does not detect obvious errors as before.
I am using objective-c and when a method implementation is missing, there is no more error. Just a crash at run time. It is also the case for protocol implementation.

Also some warnings disappeared. Before, in a switch statement with an enum, if a case is missing Xcode would signal a warning. It is no more the case.

I begin to wonder if there are other errors or warnings that just doesn't show anymore. Otherwise my iOS app compiles and seems to work as usual...

Is it possible to make Xcode detect those errors again via some settings?

Comment: You can delete your own question.

Comment: I cannot because there are answers... A moderator can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to XCode > Preferences > General tab and check the "Show live issues" box.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not errors. If they were errors, you could not compile.

They are *warnings*. What has happened is that you have suppressed the display of those warnings. You can compile even so. But you seem not to be noticing the little yellow triangle telling you there are warnings, and the warnings are not showing up in the code.

This can happen in two very different ways.

- You may have chosen Editor > Issues > Hide All Issues or Errors Only.
- Or, you may have changed the Build Settings for this project, switching off some or all Warnings. (An interesting idea could be to turn on Treat Warnings As Errors. That will stop you in your tracks if there are *any* warnings!)

Also make sure you are looking at the Buildtime side of the Issue navigator. There is now also a Runtime side, and it will not show these warnings:

[image]

[image]

One final suggestion: You say you just updated Xcode. Did you then restart the computer? My Xcode *never* works right after updating until I restart. So it's worth a try!

Comment: Editor > Issues > "All Issues" is checked
and I never changed any Build Settings. I just upgraded Xcode.
Are you telling that you still have those warnings?

Comment: Sure. Give me an example of actual code that _should_ generate a warning that isn't, and let's discuss it.

Comment: I added an example of the kind of warning you might be talking about (no implementation of the method).

Comment: Just remove the implementation of 1 method (not overwritten) in any .m file in an objective-c project. The compiler complains or not? Currently my compiler compiles just fine if I remove pieces of implementation.

Comment: Look at my screen shots. They seem to be just what you are talking about, and I've got warnings.

Comment: Restarting had no effect. More info: My project includes a static library and this problem occurs in that library. I just discover that I get those warnings in the project itself, but not for the files in my library.

Comment: Okay, that's great info but it's now a totally different question. I suggest you delete this question and ask that one, or edit this question to become that one. (Note, please, that if this is another target, it has its own build settings!)

Comment: I created a new question and tried to delete this one

Comment: Cool, let's hope you make some progress with the new one. :)