# In a static library, Xcode 8.1 does not detect when an objective-c method is not implemented

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, compiler-warnings

My objective-c project uses a static library and recently I just discovered that Xcode 8.1 does not give some warnings for the library.
When a method implementation is missing in the app itself, I get a warning. But if a method implementation is missing in the library, I get no warning. It just crashes at run time.

Same for the switch statement with an enum. If a case is missing, Xcode would signal a warning, but not in the static library.

In previous versions of Xcode, I am sure I received those warnings in my library. And I never changed any Build Settings, I just keep all the default values.

**More info:**

When I open the static library itself as a project, I get all warnings. But when I open another project that includes the library (I dropped the mylibrary.xcodeproj file in my project and add it in the Link phase), I don't have the library warnings

Comment: It's me again. — Are you sure you are _building_ the static library? When I try the same thing I tried in the other question in a static library, I get the same warnings as before.

Comment: By the way, the current version is Xcode 8.2.1.

Comment: Thank you! Your test made me think to open the library project itself. So I progress and I have at least a way to check my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Xcode. It is now working well in Xcode Version 8.3 (8E162)